# Can't connect to sqlite from eclipse?

Tags: java, database, eclipse, sqlite

Hello guys so I have this simple java to do and I am trying to connect to an sqlite database from eclipse but it doesn't work at all.

Here is my code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;


public class DatabaseConnection {

    private String pathDB="C:\\sqlite\\test.db";
    private Connection connection=null;
    private Statement statement=null;


    public DatabaseConnection(String path){
    pathDB= path;


   }

public void connect () {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        connection= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + pathDB);
        statement= connection.createStatement();
        System.out.println("Connection to " + pathDB + " "+ "successful");

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException notFoundException) {
        notFoundException.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Connection Error!");

    } catch (SQLException sqlException) {

        sqlException.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Connection Error!");
    }

    String query="Insert into Identity values(0,'issam','issam@mail.com')";
    try {
        statement.executeUpdate(query);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

public void close() {
    try {
        connection.close();
        statement.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

And the main class:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        DatabaseConnection connection= new DatabaseConnection("test.db");
        connection.connect();
        connection.close();



    }

}
```

So I have this sqlite database but whenever I run the code it always gives me : Connection to "path" was successful, no matter what path I put...

I think I have done everything correctly, I downloaded the sqlite JDBC file and added it:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRZld.png)

I tried adding a new row to a database table, but it always gives me this:

```
Connection to test.db successful
java.sql.SQLException: no such table: Identity
    at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.throwex(NativeDB.java:397)
    at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB._exec(Native Method)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Statement.executeUpdate(JDBC3Statement.java:116)
    at com.issam.iamcore.DatabaseConnection.connect(DatabaseConnection.java:41)
    at com.issam.iamcore.Main.main(Main.java:10)
java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database   (Connection is closed)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:890)
    at org.sqlite.core.CoreStatement.internalClose(CoreStatement.java:109)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Statement.close(JDBC3Statement.java:35)
    at com.issam.iamcore.DatabaseConnection.close(DatabaseConnection.java:63)
    at com.issam.iamcore.Main.main(Main.java:11)
```

Any help would be appreeciated, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You have successfully connected to the database, but did not create table `Identity` before executing insert query, as it says in the stack trace:

```
Connection to test.db successful
java.sql.SQLException: no such table: Identity
```

Call this before inserting a row:

```
String createQuery = "CREATE TABLE Identity (id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, name TEXT, email TEXT)";
statement.executeUpdate(createQuery);
```

Comment: I don't think the problem is here. I ALWAYS get the succesfull connection message whatever path I put, so there must be a problem. And I had the identity table created in the database.
Edit: When I tried this, I got: "table Identity already exists" and "UNIQUE constraint failed: Identity.id"

Comment: It is a normal behavior when you get the successful connection message, because SQLite creates the file for you if it does not exist on the path. Try different path so the SQLite will create a new file for you and after that try to create the table and insert the row again.

Comment: I don't think you got my point. The path is normally used to show where is the database file so it can connect to it, if I give a random path, there wont be any file and connection wont be successful normally. I just tried putting another path, and it didnt create any file, and I still get the "identity table already exists" message..